# Mysql query except

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a query like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Carta_ID
FROM Carta_Alarme
INNER JOIN Alarme ON Carta_Alarme.Alarme_ID = Alarme.ID
WHERE (
YEAR( Alarme.dtOcorrencia ) = 2011
) NOT
IN (

SELECT DISTINCT Carta_ID
FROM Carta_Alarme
INNER JOIN Alarme ON Carta_Alarme.Alarme_ID = Alarme.ID
WHERE (
YEAR( Alarme.dtOcorrencia ) = 2012
)
)
```

The result of first Select is (1, 5, 6). The result of the other select after "NOT IN" is (1,2,3,4,5) but the result of the total query is (1,2,3,4,5) and i need only (6).

So what i need is an EXCEPT between this selects and what i get is an INTERSECT

Comment: That `NOT IN (...)` seems not correct. It should be `AND Carta_ID NOT IN (...)`

Comment: It might be helpful to show some sample data rows to make it clearer as to why you want to select a certain row.

Comment: Convert those `YEAR(Alarme.dtOcorrencia) = 2011` conditions to `Alarme.dtOcorrencia >= '2011-01-01' AND Alarme.dtOcorrencia < '2012-01-01'` if you hope having indexes used by the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Carta_ID
FROM Carta_Alarme
INNER JOIN Alarme ON Carta_Alarme.Alarme_ID = Alarme.ID
GROUP BY Carta_ID
HAVING sum(YEAR(Alarme.dtOcorrencia) = 2011) > 0 
   and sum(YEAR(Alarme.dtOcorrencia) = 2012) = 0
```

Comment: It's interesting, I can not catch up with the idea.

Comment: It works like that: If you group by `Carta_ID` then you select only those who have entries in 2011 and none in 2012. `YEAR(Alarme.dtOcorrencia) = 2011` is a condition that will return `1` if `true` and `0` if not. Summing up all `true` values and you can see which contain 2011/2012 entries

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Carta_ID
FROM Carta_Alarme
INNER JOIN Alarme ON Carta_Alarme.Alarme_ID = Alarme.ID
WHERE (
YEAR( Alarme.dtOcorrencia ) = 2011
) AND Carta_ID NOT
IN (

SELECT DISTINCT Carta_ID
FROM Carta_Alarme
INNER JOIN Alarme ON Carta_Alarme.Alarme_ID = Alarme.ID
WHERE (
YEAR( Alarme.dtOcorrencia ) = 2012
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4acc9/5/0)

This is effectively a [minus set operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#EXCEPT_operator)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.Carta_ID
FROM Carta_Alarme ca
INNER JOIN Alarme a ON ca.Alarme_ID = a.ID
left join (SELECT DISTINCT Carta_ID
           FROM Carta_Alarme
           INNER JOIN Alarme ON Carta_Alarme.Alarme_ID = Alarme.ID
           WHERE YEAR( Alarme.dtOcorrencia ) = 2012) ca2 on ca2.Carta_id = ca.Carta_id
WHERE YEAR( a.dtOcorrencia ) = 2011
      and ca2.Carta_id is null
```